# Camelot/Arthurian paperback fantasy/romance about a failed attempt to find the Grail

Tags: story-identification, novel, arthurian, holy-grail

In 1997 I read a paperback adventure romance where a Knight of the Round Table, or an aspiring one maybe, fails in his quest to find the Grail because he is waylaid and bewitched by probably Morgan/Morgana.

I think his name was Sir Drian/Dryn, which would make him a minor blip of a character in Mallory/Le Morte d'Arthur.